# Arduino Uno error resp=0x27

Tags: arduino-uno, error

I use the Chinese copy of board. My code is right, but when i upload to board, it print me this:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x27
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

Do you know, what is it?

Answer (score -1):

It could be a number of things that we haven't enough information to diagnose. But 'not responding' is quite likely the result of the wrong- or no port or board being selected, or failure of the connection to your computer, or failure of your operating system to recognize the board.
Editing more information into your question would help: What board & chip (is it an Uno clone?), your OS, whether your board was or wasn't recognized by the OS (Windows) or the IDE (macOS), whether you've installed a CH340 or other alternative USB driver if your board requires it (most Chinese Uno clones require some version of the CH340 driver; macOS usually has it built in; Windows usually doesn't). Do some more digging and flesh out your question a lot more - you'll be able to get much better help. And you may not even need it by then!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!